# How to generate RABL instead of ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to generate RABL view instead of HTML.erb

Am using the following command

```
rails generate controller users new create update edit destroy index show
```

Am getting all .erb views. I need rabl view.

Rabl is included in my GemFile

```
gem 'rabl'
```

Comment: File -> new -> `show.rabl`

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: @ckruse Am using command line sorry! :(

Comment: @madhairsilence `touch show.rabl`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a generator which creates 'rabl' files just like scaffolding?

As far as I know,

Nope. There isn't a generator inside Rabl gem.

As ckruse said; 
File -> new -> show.rabl

Comment: Am using command to generate!!! You can see the question where I mentioned what command am using!